# After restoring Mysql databases, getting error on *second* load

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

It is difficult to put a meaningful title on this question, but what is essentially happening is that I had to re-create my MySQL "mysql" (system) database and now every time I load this data, MySQL will start and operate normally *exactly once*.

Everything is fully functional. I can connect, everything works well, etc.

The *second* time I try to start MySQL (after a reboot, etc.) I get an error `[ERROR] [FATAL] InnoDB: Tablespace id is 2 in the data dictionary but in file ./mysql/innodb_index_stats.ibd it is 14!` in the logs.

MySQL keeps trying to start every minute as long as the "service" is started (this is on current Ubuntu, using .deb packages from repo), however, it crashes every time with this error.

It looks like this is some type of corruption, but since it will load correctly *once* and work just fine, I assume it can be corrected.... please tell me it can be corrected.

Interestingly, I'm also getting this error from "journalctl -xe" when I try to start the service:

```
    Sep 25 21:20:23 xan4 audit[23737]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/proc/23713/task/23737/mem" pid=2...
```

Thanks, in advance, MySQL experts, for helping me figure this out.

--mobrien

Comment: it sounds like you are copying a set of files from /var/lib/mysql while the server is running. Doesn't work.

Comment: After about 24 hours of the error log filling up, it "just worked". However, after doing a package upgrade of MySql, now the error is back, preventing it from completing the package upgrade... Going to wait 24 hours to see if the same thing happens, but not holding my breath.

Comment: Also, @e4c5, I'm not copying the files while the server is running. I've been working at this for hours and hours and have been operating this database server since 2008. I know better than that! :-) Thanks for trying to help, though.

Comment: It actually takes about 10-12 hours. Every time the server "restarts" (or the PC restarts) it fills up the logs with these errors for about 10 hours, then magically starts... WTF?